# Symfony Get an exeption when error 404

Tags: symfony

I need to get an exeption when i have an error 404,

so in my config i have add :

```
exception:
    codes:
        'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
        'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
    messages:
        'Safebrands\SurveillanceApiBundle\Exception\MyExceptionWithASafeMessage': true
```

and in my MyExceptionWithASafeMessage i have :

```
class MyExceptionWithASafeMessage extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

But when i get an error 404, that don't change anything, i have already error 404

Comment: where in your config is this?

Comment: My config is in a bundle create 'common-bundle'

Comment: you need to give us something more than that. as it stands I have no idea what youre trying to do

Comment: When i have an error 404, i would like to get my own exception.
So in my config i give the message for this exception, so actually, i need to return "test", and i don't understand why that return me again error 404, and not 'test'

Comment: what do you mean 'get my own exception', do you mean a custom 404 page? or change the exception altogether?

Comment: change the exception, actually error 404 give me an html page, i just want get a value, without the html, its possible to do this with custom ?
Sorry for my bad english.